# Rails migration refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

In migrations we can write in following way

```
t.integer :escalated_by, escalated_to, query_id
```

But I don't like this way.

Rather I would like something like code below:

```
  def self.up
    create_table :query_escalations do |t|
      t.integer do
        :escalated_by
        :escalated_to
        :query_id
      end
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I think this is more readable.
Does rails supports this way? or is there any way similar to this?

Comment: remove the do end, add commas at the end of all fields except the last in your alternative and you are good to go :)  On a serious note, can you explain why your alternative is better?

Comment: Yes Vijay, I have done this in the 2nd line of the post itself. But in this style it is not possible to give other options e.g. default values to the fields. With my approach it will be possible to provide different options for different fields and it will also reduce writing t.integer, t.string etc. for each field. I can write it like def self.up
    create_table :query_escalations do |t|
      t.integer do
        :escalated_by, :default => 20
        :escalated_to, :default => 1
        :query_id
      end
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Rails does not suppor that style. And if you want that style then you will have to do a lot of work.

Migration is complex piece of code. I will suggest to stick with what rails provides.

For what it's work up and down will be instance methods in Rails 3.1 instead of being class methods.